# Positioning over image and under image

Tags: html, css

Good day. I have a code:

```
 <div style=\"position:relative;height:auto;padding:5px;float:left;\">
 <img id=\"avimg\" src=".$uinfo["avatar_url"]."><p id=\"act-await\" style='position:absolute;top:13px;left:24px;'><i id=".$uinfo['id']." class=\"icon-checkmark\" onclick=\"accfr(this.id);\"></i><br><i id=".$uinfo['id']." onclick=\"decfr(this.id);\" class=\"icon-cancel-2\"></i></p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #avimg:hover {
opacity:0.3;
 -moz-opacity:0.3; 
 filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
#act-await {
    display:none;
}
#avimg:hover + #act-await {
    display:block;
}
```

All works. But I need a link under an image. When I make this, block #act-await not showing (when mouse over).

```
 <div style=\"position:relative;height:auto;padding:5px;float:left;\">
 <img id=\"avimg\" src=".$uinfo["avatar_url"]."><br><a href=\"\"><font size=\"1\">".$uinfo['name']. "<br>".$uinfo['surname']."</font></a>
 <p id=\"act-await\" style='position:absolute;top:2px;text-align:center;'><i id=".$uinfo['id']." class=\"icon-checkmark\" onclick=\"accfr(this.id);\"></i><br><i id=".$uinfo['id']." onclick=\"decfr(this.id);\" class=\"icon-cancel-2\"></i></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what the link is yet use the pound key. You have an empty href

```
<a href ="#"......
```

In you case

```
<a href=\"#\".......
```

And when you have a link replace the pound key with it